# ReadTimeoutError - Why is this occurring?

Tags: python, request, runtime

I encounter the following ReadTimeoutError, the request not responding and not giving out any output (in the state of runnning non-stop):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1374, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
TimeoutError: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 451, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 340, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4990): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\getSupplierName-api\test.py", line 35, in <module>
    response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=10)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 532, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4990): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

The request code is as follows:

```
import requests
import json
import glob


url = "..."

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
path = "..../*.pdf"

list_of_path = glob.glob(path)
print("Number of files:", len(list_of_path))
for i in list_of_path:
    print(i)
    payload = json.dumps({
                    "file_path": i,
                    "company_id": "abcde",

    })
    
    response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=10)
    print(response.json()['payload'])
```

Not sure why this is happening. The same issue happens with or without running in virtualenv. It was running fine when I ran it (many times) without any virtualenv, then I created the virtualenv on my machine and ran it again, it's working fine. But on the next day, the error occurs when I try to run it.
Appreciate any help, many thanks!

Comment: "ReadTimeoutError, causing the request not responding" is wrong that is the opposite : "the request not responding in given time => ReadTimeoutError"

Comment: So the server you contact is on your machine (as the IP is 127.0.0.1) so you may look what happen on this side (server) to know why it is long

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the service that was listening for at port 4990 is not listening anymore. I suppose you know what service this is, so I recommend to check if it's running.

After you start the service that listen at port 4990, there are two ways to confirm you the port is really open and listening:

1. If you are using linux, you can check what ports are listening in your machine with the following command:

`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

2. You can try to connect to the port 4990 using telnet:

`telnet 127.0.0.1 4990`

If the telnet works, the output should be something like this:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: So I think I am able to connect to the port, is the result a blank cmd?

Comment: Hello @Danny! If you used telnet to connect, the output should be the three lines that I included in my answer. But how about the service that listen at the port 4990, do you know what service this is? Have you found out how to check if it's running and how to start it?